# How to use both static files and media together

Tags: python, django

Is it possible to use both static files and media in a project? because all tutorials use only one of them.

```
MEDIA_URL= 'media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'

STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = BASE_DIR / 'static/
```

I wrote this to setting. How am supposed to modify `urls.py`?

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include('pages.urls')),
    path('users/',include('users.urls')),
    path('users/',include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I wrote it this way but how should I add static urls?

Comment: *I wrote it this way but how should I add static urls?* -   ***urlpatterns*** is a list  you can use `+` to concate another list as you can see you've concated value of `static()` which return a list you can do the same for media

Comment: so it wont lead project to an error?

Comment: No, @Nicolas_Darksoul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add the two lists generated by the `static` functions, so:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('pages.urls')),
    path('users/', include('users.urls')),
    path('users/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Note however that Django does *not* serve static or media files in production, and that you this will have to set up nginx, apache, or another webserver to do so.

Comment: srry i  dont know about them can you pls share a link about webservers , and can i use them while i practice in local host?

Comment: @Nicolas_Darksoul: yes, it only will no longer work with `DEBUG = False`, since Django's hosting of static/media files in not very efficient (and likely unsafe) https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/deployment/#:~:text=Serving%20static%20files%20in%20production,static%20file%20server%20and%20served.